# set password for user account from a fileun issue

Tags: unix, ubuntu

I want to create user account n times in UNIX
after creating the account I want to set password reads line by line from  a file called password.txt
but I do not know how to do that!
my bash script contains this so far:

```
sudu useradd user
passwd
```

I have stuck on this point !, I do not know how to set password from a file?
what command should  I use?

I want something like this but I want to read pass word not user name

```
for i in `more pass.txt `
do
echo $i
adduser $i

done
```

Answer (score 0):

Have the code like this

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in `cat unpw.csv`; do
  UN=`echo $i | cut -f1 -d','`
  PW=`echo $i | cut -f2 -d','`
  ENCPW=`echo $PW | mkpasswd -s`
  echo useradd -p $ENCPW -m $UN
done
```

where the input file unpw.csv has

```
user1,password1
user2,password2
user3,password3
```

**PS: Make sure that mkpasswd is installed**

Comment: the output is not the password that is in the file

Comment: p9/cvdIsJK63k this is the first output and my password in the txt file is pass1   !!!

Comment: It is encrypted password